# "Failed to authenticate user" exception in the c# Hello world sample of Docusign Signature Appliance demo

Tags: docusignapi, digital-signature

I have installed the trial version of DocuSign SA client for Windows desktop. Then I have checked out the [docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes) repository and ran the C# Hello World demo in the dsa-local folder. The code from the demo is explained in the [DocuSign Local API guide](https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api/guides/hello_world_quickstart_local) from which I have acquired the GitHub link in the first place.

As mentioned in the [Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/dsa-api/guides/quickstart_local) section of the guide, I have created a Developer SandBox account. I have used the credentials of that account in the code, but the SAPI.Logon method fails at line 47 of [Program.cs](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes/blob/master/dsa-local/Hello-World-examples/C%23/HelloWorld/Program.cs) file.

I have also opened Docusign SA Prepare & Sign tool that was installed as part of the Docusign SA client and tried to sign a PDF. While doing so, I was prompted the credentials and I have entered the same credentials. But I got "Invalid username or password, operation canceled" error dialog.

I have also ensured that old credentials for DocuSign are not cached in my desktop. How can I make the user authentication succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured the DSA Client to point prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net appliance? 
[image]
You can also try to register again to https://go.docusign.com/signup/dsa-developer using the same credentials or new ones. Then make sure your credentials are correct by testing them at https://webapp-dsa-devctr.docusign.net/. Once correct use them in the SAPI.Logon method at line 47 of Program.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something is wrong with your account details. Please contact our DSA Support by filling-in our [web form](https://support.docusign.com/apex/CSP_ContactSupportFunnel?channels=2#csf), or by sending an email to: DSAsupport@docusign.com